# What should be the power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What should the power set of S = {ø, {ø}} be?

Ideally it should be {ø, {ø}, {ø, {ø}}. I think.

But is it really?

Or is it just ø?

I’m confused. Can you help me out a bit please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The powerset of a set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ elements. So your answer is wrong. What is the power set of $\{x,y\}$? It is $\{\emptyset, \{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\}\}$. Now replace $x$ by $\emptyset$ and $y$ by $\{\emptyset\}.$

$$\begin{array}\\
&\vert& x  \text{ replace by }  \emptyset \text{ and }y \text{ replace by } \{\emptyset\}\\
\hline
\emptyset& \vert &\emptyset\\
\{x\}&\vert&\{\emptyset\}\\
\{y\}&|&\{\{\emptyset\}\}\\
\{x,y\}&|&\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\\
\{\emptyset, \{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\}\}&|&\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}
\end{array}$$

Comment: So you’re saying it should be {ø, {ø}, S}, right? Considering ø gets repeated twice?

Comment: I hope I don't. I will extend my answer.

Comment: {ø, {ø}, {{ø}}, S}, is this right?

Comment: @Dora yes, now it is right

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, the cardinality of the powerset of a set of $n$ elements has $2^n$ elements. Hence we are looking for a set consisting of $4$ elements. Moreover, for every set $A$, the empty set $\varnothing $ and $A$ are always subsets of $A$, the so called improper subsets. In your case, improper subsets are $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$. Remaining two subsets are the singletons, that is subsets with exactly one element, namely $\{\varnothing\}$, and $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$.